# WordPress Custom Post Type Navigation + Children

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

UPDATED: 5/08/2010

WordPress has now added an additional technique to display the items from a custom post-type if the post-type is set to Hierarchical.

What I would like to do though is make it so the post items have the .current_page_item class when selected in the navigation.

Does anyone know of a function to achieve this?

```
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'post_type'=>'testimonials',
      'title_li'=> __('Testimonials')
    );
    wp_list_pages( $args ); 
    ?>
```

Thanks,
George

Comment: Willing to pay $100 to get this fixed, will Paypal it to the first person to provide a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

with "Custom post type ui" plugin, set Hierarchical = true.

```
    register_post_type('Portfolios', array( 'label' => 'Portfolios','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post',**'hierarchical' => true**,'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),'query_var' => true,'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields','revisions','thumbnail','page-attributes',),'labels' => array (
      'name' => 'Portfolios',
      'singular_name' => '',
      'menu_name' => 'Portfolios',
      'add_new' => 'Add Portfolios',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolios',
      'edit' => 'Edit',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolios',
      'new_item' => 'New Portfolios',
      'view' => 'View Portfolios',
      'view_item' => 'View Portfolios',
      'search_items' => 'Search Portfolios',
      'not_found' => 'No Portfolios Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Portfolios Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent Portfolios',
    ),) );
```